# unable to get intellisense for knockout.js file

Tags: asp.net, intellisense, knockout.js

i am working on asp.net website and we are using knockout.js. I am not able to get javascript intellisense for knowkcout.js file. I tried adding the below snippet but still i am not getting any intellisense.

```
<% if(false){ %>
    <script src="knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>
```

This is how my head block looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<% if(false){ %>
    <script src="knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(function() {

function viewModel() {
    firstName = ko.observable();
    lastName = ko.observable();

}

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());




 });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try putting it in the head tag as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put along with the `knockoutjs.2.0.0.js` file an other one - debug version of kcnockoutjs `knockout-2.0.0.debug.js` and Visual Studio would be able pick intellisense up. You do not need  including this file using `<script src="" .. />`.

Works for me on Visual Studio 2010

Download [knockout-2.0.0.debug.js — Knockout 2.0.0 (debug build)](https://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.0.0.debug.js) from CodePlex

Comment: not sure i am able to follow you but i added debug file using <script src="knockout-2.0.0.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>. still no luck. I have debug and prod version of these files. can you post your markup in the answer please?

Comment: @Asdfg : remove `<script src` and just copy this file along with `2.0.0.js`, dows this help? Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: i m using visual studio 2008. you mean copy it to the same folder as 2.0.0.js file is in and remove references to the debug.2.0.0.js file from the markup?

Comment: @Asdfg : exactly, but I've not checked this with VS2008, hope it helps

Comment: Just checked, I'm using Visual Studio 2011 Dev preview