# Knockout intellisense in VS2010 when inside a namespace

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, knockout.js, intellisense

I have a javascript file that contains my knockout viewModel. I have added a reference to the knockout debug file but intellisense only works when I'm outside the namespace curly braces:

```
/// <reference path="knockout-2.0.0.debug.js" />

// YES! I get intellisense here :-)

(function (window, $, ko, undefined) {
// ... lots of js
// NO intellisense in here :-(

})(window, jQuery, ko);
```

It would seem that the `ko` in my namespace signature is 'hiding' the real ko namespace. **Is there a way around this** other than changing my namespace signature to:

```
(function (window, $, myKo, undefined) {
```

(Maybe I am missing something with namespaces? Do I even need to pass `ko` into my namespace?)

Comment: Related post [unable to get intellisense for knockout.js file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9519044/1577396)

Answer (score 2):

Intellisense is not clever enough to follow the reference. Arguably you do not need to inject references into your 'namespace' like this anyway. I would argue it's not even a namespace, it's just a closure. Considering normal use case, a namespace is a global container for a bunch of related code. An application might have a single reference in global scope, and this would be considered the application's namespace. Other libraries such as jQuery will register their own values in global scope, which might be considered a namespace. In other cases you can wrap the entire scope in a closure, registering namespaces within the closure, so you never need to touch global scope.

I can see why you might want to inject a reference into your function though. This sort of follows an interface pattern so you can potentially swap these variables out with mocked versions. Unfortunately I don't think you can infer the reference to Intellisense, and it is for the same reason (i.e. you could swap it out with anything) that it cannot tell exactly what these objects contain.

In the statically typed world we actually define interface objects, which allows Intellisense to reflect on injected references, asserting that they at least have the methods defined on the interface.

I think the only option you really have to preserve Intellisense is to refer to the global references that these libraries define.

**Update**

It looks like Microsoft have actually used type annotations to allow you to explicitly reference the type of an argument to a function. I tested this version of implying a reference with jQuery

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js" />

(function ($) {
    /// <param name="$" type="jQuery">
    ///     A rererence to jQuery
    /// </param>



})(jQuery);
```

The jQuery intellisense version declares the return type of jQuery. Supposing Knockout has intellisense that defines the type you could annotate your function in the same way. In general I think you can declare an object type like this:

```
var someObject = (function() {
    /// <returns type="someObject" />

    // implementation here, returning object
})();

function (a) {
    /// <summary>
    ///      This function requires a to be a reference to a someObject type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param" type="someObject">
    ///     A reference to a someObject type
    /// </param>
    /// <returns type="String" />

    // we now have intellisense on a, treating it as someObject
}
```

So if you are prepared to go through the process of adding annotations, you can get Intellisense to work .

Comment: I updated my answer with a potential solution. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Matt. I add the jQuery reference and jQuery intellisense now works. However, adding a reference to knockout and then adding "/// <param name="ko" type="ko" />" inside the function still does not trigger intellisense into life. I just get the usual "constructor, hasOwnProperty, etc." list that all objects get.